# Calling a method in a Java object from JNI returns error

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I know there are many questions like this asked before, but I just cannot figure out why my code is not working. So I have a simple class that stores a String:

```
public class JniString {
    private String mString;

    public JniString() {}

    public String getString() {
        return mString;
    }

    public void setString(String s) {
        mString = s;
    }
}
```

My JNI code (in C), which is supposed to take JniString object as argument, call setString() function to store some data, and return an integer:

```
JNIEXPORT jint
        JNICALL Java_com_sample_MyClass_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject jniString) {
    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/sample/JniString");
    jmethodID methodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "setString", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    jstring placeholder = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "placeholder");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, clazz, methodId, placeholder);

    return 1;
}
```

And my Java code:

```
JniString jniString = new JniString();
// Call test() JNI function with jniString as argument
```

But for some reason, this keeps failing with the following error message:

```
05-24 23:27:23.099    7575-7575/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.sample.JniString.setString(java.lang.String) on instance of java.lang.Class<com.sample.JniString>
05-24 23:27:23.099    7575-7575/? A/art﹕ art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to CallVoidMethod
```

I read something about having to call NewGlobalRef() or something since ICS (I'm running my app on KitKat+) over here: http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html

But I can't understand what the blog post is saying, or where I would put that in the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I modified the JNI code to be the following:

```
JNIEXPORT jint
            JNICALL Java_com_sample_MyClass_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject jniString) {
        jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, jniString);
        jmethodID methodId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "setString", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

        jstring placeholder = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "placeholder");
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, jniString, methodId, placeholder);

        return 1;
    }
```

But now I'm getting a different error:

```
05-25 19:11:02.832    8802-8802/com.sample E/art﹕ JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1 (should be 0x100001)
05-25 19:11:02.850    8802-8802/com.sample A/art﹕ art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x1
```

Comment: I'm impressed by how on-point the error message is.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call an instance method via the class instead of via an instance. The second parameter needs to be an object instance of `JniString`, probably in this case `jniString`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im still very new to JNI, can you show me a code that will work?

Comment: You can't replace the second parameter of the call with the text I have already given you?

Answer (score -1):

The second parameter of `CallVoidMethod()` should not be `clazz`. A nonstatic method needs its `this` object. Use the `jniString` parameter instead

There's no warning from the compiler because a `jclass` is derived from `jobject`. Typesafe JNI isn't.

Comment: There's no warning from the compiler because there is no error, and nothing to warn about, *because* `jclass` extends `jobject`. The call could be correct: for example, you could be calling `Class.getName().`